# Notation/terminology: Existence of a nonleast element which is less of any element of a set

Tags: notation, terminology, order-theory

Let $A$ is a subset of a partial order $X$.

Are there any name and/or notation for the following predicate $P(A)$?

$P(A)$ iff there is a non-least element $x$ of $X$ which is a subelement of each element of $A$ (that is $\forall y\in A:x\leq y$)?

Comment: Sorry, misread. Is this different from a lower bound?

Comment: @GitGud Once you see all the letters it makes more sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In set theory, we would probably say: "$A$ has a non-empty intersection."
2. So if you're working a complete lattice, you could say: "$A$ has a non-trivial meet."
3. Otherwise, I would say: "$A$ has a non-trivial lower bound."

Comment: Of course, if these aren't snappy enough, you can always just make up your own.

Comment: e.g. "$A$ overlaps" or "$A$ is supported"

Comment: I like 3 the best since it's the most general.